# How do I replace this tile/marble transition in a tiled bathroom?

Tags: flooring, tile, transition

I planned to keep this marble piece for the transition to the new tile floor in the bathroom, but I broke it during demo. What’s the best way to replace it, or should I use a different transition?

Bonus points for the pros/cons of a marble floor transition versus alternatives.

[image: floor]

Comment: They still sell marble thresholds at places like Home Depot.  Any reason you can't just buy another one?

Comment: Yes, I could buy another. I just didn’t see them when we bought the tile ... of course, I wasn’t looking, since I planned to reuse the old one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1: Replace with another marble transition**

Marble transitions are still sold.  Replacing a broken one with another would preserve the original look of your floor.  However, marble isn't the most durable material to make a transition out of, and it may look out of place if it's the only marble thing in the area.  They're also kind of clunky because of their thickness.

**Option 2: Embedded tile transition**

There are a number of extruded metal (usually aluminum) transitions designed to be installed in the mortar underneath the tile.  These extrusions can transition between even or uneven flooring heights and present a cleaner, more flush transition between floors.  The caveat here is that the transition placement might be odd, depending on where the wood floor stops in the doorway.

They typically look similar this, but may vary in thickness and profile depending on the height difference:

[image]

**Option 3: Wood transition**

If you can find a wood transition that matches your existing wood (or an unfinished one you can stain to match), you could replace the marble with a wooden transition of similar profile.  The difficulty in matching existing, aged hardwood is not to be underestimated though.  Hardwood tends to darken with age and UV exposure, so a transition that matches fairly well now might not in 5-10 years.  Alternately, you could stain the wood a different color to match wood elsewhere.  Sometimes it's better to go with a completely different color than to get a "close but not quite" match that looks off.

**Option 4: No transition**

It is possible to butt wood against tile without a transition.  A Google Image search shows many instances of tile being butted against wood without any sort of transitional trim piece, and all of them look pretty good.  This depends on your tile floor being the same height as your wood floor and both floors being cut cleanly and precisely at the transition.  If either of those things isn't true or true enough, I would stay away from this method.  No transition and a rough edge will look sloppy and unfinished.